# String Value to JSON Spark SQL

Tags: python, sql, json, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

My goal: Extract the data in the string below into 4 columns in spark sql. I'd like to select it as below:

```
select raw.PostingType, raw.AccountRef.name, raw.AccountRef.value, raw.AccountRef.AcctNum
```

```
{PostingType=Credit, AccountRef={name=John Doe, value=27, AcctNum=111111}}
```

What I did/My Problem: I attempted to use the "from_json" function, I was not sure how to use it when it has a nested json it in.

My question: How can I extract the data in this string into individual columns?

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of doing it:

- Use `from_json` function ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/from_json.html)) - you just need to provide a correct schema to it. Use following string as 2nd parameter to the `from_json` function: `'PostingType string, AccountRef struct<name: string, value: int, AcctNum: long>'`:

```sql
with tbl as (
  select from_json(raw, 'PostingType string, AccountRef struct<name: string, value: int, AcctNum: long>') as raw
  from some_table)
select raw.PostingType, raw.AccountRef.name, raw.AccountRef.value, raw.AccountRef.AcctNum
  from tbl
```

- use `get_json_object` function ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/get_json_object.html)) to extract individual pieces using JSON path expressions, like this:

```sql
select get_json_object(raw, '$.PostingType') as PostingType,
  get_json_object(raw, '$.AccountRef'.name) as name,
  ...
from some_table
```

- Use `:` operator ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/colonsign.html)) to extract values using the JSON Path expressions similar to the previous example.

P.S. I tried the question on ChatGPT, and it generated a correct code!